# jQuery shorthand for tabindex naming

Tags: jquery

is there any way to shorten between all tabindex=4 to tabindex=40? Thanks

```
$('[tabindex="4"]...[tabindex="40"]').on({
    focus: function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    },
    blur: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

dont wanna type all the indexs there thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("[tabindex]").filter(function() {
    var index = parseInt($(this).attr("tabindex"), 10);
    return index >= 4 && index <= 40;
}).on(....);
```

`.filter()` takes an existing jQuery collection and reduces it to the elements for which the function returns `true`. This gets the value of the `tabindex` attribute and checks whether it's between 4 and 40.

Comment: You may want a little explanation of what [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) does, just for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `for` loop:

```
for (var index = 4; index <= 40; ++index) {
    $('[tabindex="' + index + '"]').on({
        focus: function() {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        },
        blur: function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```